# Delete AWS Cloud formation stack with resources created by it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Based on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/delete-stack.html) page I can do:

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack \
    --stack-name my-stack
```

It says I can attach the command:
`[--retain-resources <value>]`

Does that mean that if I don't specify that line, all the resources created by the stack will be removed? I'm trying to delete everything generated by the stack, which is a lot.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those resources will be kept if you specify the `[--retain-resources <value>]`, if you dont Cloudformation will delete all the resources in the stack name (including the nested stacks as well) you are providing given you have permissions to do. If any of the resources inside the cloudformation stack has retain policy set they won't be deleted.

> During deletion, AWS CloudFormation deletes the stack but does not delete the retained resources.

From the same page [aws cloudformation delete-stack](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/delete-stack.html)

You might wanna read this too [How do I retain some of my resources when I delete an AWS CloudFormation stack?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/delete-cf-stack-retain-resources/#:%7E:text=To%20keep%20certain%20resources%20when,event%20of%20a%20stack%20deletion.)

You can specify the [retain policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) as well in cloudformation template.

Comment: but how can I delete the stack with full resources deletion?

Comment: I'm not trying to keep anything

Comment: @Arturo Does this answers your question?

Comment: I think so, I'm testing it now, one sec

Comment: Yes it did, I'll accept it in a min +1 thanks

Comment: Same question as @ElKePoN . What if I wanted to delete ALL resources, even these with retain policy or some other flag?

Comment: What is the behaviour when deletion is performed via the UI and can this be controlled?

Comment: I have the same question as @variable; does deleting stack using the console has the same behavior as you are telling in this chain ?